# Unable to change image for the button in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

In my code for checkmark I used button to change images for selected and unselected but unable to implement if I click on it's changing to unchecked but again selecting button it's unable to change to check image can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

```
var checkedImage = UIImage(named: "check")! as UIImage
var uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheck")! as UIImage
var isChecked: Bool = true
var checkMarkSelected = 0

checkMarkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

func checkMarkAction(button : UIButton) {
        if isChecked == true {
            checkMarkButton.setImage(checkedImage, for: .selected)
            isChecked = false
            checkMarkSelected = 1
        }
        else {
            checkMarkButton.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: .normal)
            isChecked = true
            checkMarkSelected = 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Step 1: Select your CheckUIButton and set Image “Uncheck” (state config must be Default in attribute inspector)
Step 2: In attribute inspector change state config to Selected and set image “Check”
Step 3: Put following code in your UIButton action.

@IBAction func checkclick(_ sender: UIButton) {

        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    }
```

Comment: your code was working fine thanks a lot but here how can I send a parameter when button is selected ?

Comment: that means if I select image check then need to pass 1 if not 0 how can I do it @Dhaval Solanki

Comment: you can use boolean variable to maintain this situation. For Example if you select check then a=1 and boolean is true otherwise it false.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3**

```
  @IBAction func btntouchupInsideevent(_ sender: UIButton)
        {
            if yourbtnOutletName.currentImage == "YourCheckImageName"
            {
                yourbtnOutletName.setImage(YourUncheckImage.imagetype, for: .normal)

            }
            else
            {
                btnIsEventRecouring.setImage(YourcheckImage.imagetype, for: .normal)

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add the action in the **viewDidLoad()** function of your view controller for that button or, **if you are declaring it in a stand-alone UIButton inherited class** in order to reuse it in the future in many view controllers, you should **add the target in the initialiser of the UIButton**.

If the code is written in that way is even strange that Xcode is not giving you warnings...

EDIT: This is a code snippet of how I would do it

```
//Comments

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  //link this to the checkmark buttons
  //subclass UIButton making a button with the property isChecked: Bool
  @IBOutlet weak var checkmarkButton: UICheckButton!

  var checkMarkSelected = 0

  override function viewDidLoad() {
    //do stuff with your viewdidload
  }

  //link this to the checkmark buttons
  @IBAction func checkMarkAction(sender: UICheckButton) {
        if sender.isChecked == false {
            let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "check")
            checkMarkButton.setImage(checkedImage, for: .normal)
            sender.isChecked = true
            checkMarkSelected += checkMarkSelected
        } else {
            let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheck")
            checkMarkButton.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: .normal)
            sender.isChecked = false
            checkMarkSelected -= checkMarkSelected
        }
  }
```

Comment: Another error in your implementation is that the selected state end when you remove your finger from the screen as standard behaviour, so that will make you lose the checked state when you lift your thumb from the screen...

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var termsAndConditionsButton: UIButton!

    if termsAndConditionsButton.isSelected == true {
        termsAndConditionsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkboxOff"), for: .normal)
        termsAndConditionsButton.isSelected=false

    }
    else{
        termsAndConditionsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkboxOn"), for: .normal)
        termsAndConditionsButton.isSelected=true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this on IBAction function

```
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    
    if sender.isSelected == true {
      sender.isSelected = true
      sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_on"), for: UIControl.State.selected)
    }else{
      sender.isSelected = false
      sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_off"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
```